# Home folder is too big for its contents

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am new to the windows 7 environment, and frankly I'm not liking it. I'm using windows merely out of need. I like to keep my machine as clean as possible, so I was looking at the disk space. I have plenty of it available, but the used space seemed too much for what I have on the computer, which is practically nothing. Then I went to check my home directory. I right-click on it, and select properties. I see that my home directory has a reported size of 5.58 GB, and a size on disk of 5.62GB.

This is too much because I have only 4 images sitting on the desktop, and nothing else.

I wanted to see what was using all that space up. So I went folder by folder checking their properties, and none of them seems big. Then I selected them all, and their total size is of 333MB.

This is a brand new computer which I've used only to SSH into my linux server.

So the question then is, why the heck is the home directory 5.58GB in size? And of course, what can I do about this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which folder are we talking about here? `\Users\<username>`?

Comment: Yes, that is the one.

Comment: How large is your `\Users\<you>\Downloads`?

Comment: 315 MB is the size of the Downloads folder. All other folders are empty or contain only the default content that the windows installation adds to them like sample images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could possibly be your appdata folder, this tends to get full of crap if some of your apps arnt cleaning up after themselves properly. Try installing this, and running the cleaner, this will clean up any files that your system no longer needs.

http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/

If this doesn't work, you can always create a new username, then once you have moved anything other you want to keep, go to control panel, system, advanced system settings, userprofiles (settings), then delete the old profile. This will free up all the space it takes up then. Just make sure you copy anything you want to keep to your new user account first though as once its deleted its not coming back.

Comment: Well, you gave me an idea. First of all, I am always reluctant to install programs on my computer. As I said, keeping them clean is important for me. So, I decided to look for anything that was already on the computer that might help me clean it up.

I found under Accessories->System Tools a little program called Disk Cleanup. It helped me freed up 7+ GB most of that were temporary files. Now my home folder is down to 1.79 GB, which is still too much for my 333 total in all my files under that folder. Now I'm guessing there are some hidden folders in the home directory. Thanks.

Comment: Well, well, you were right, it seems there is an appdata folder that is hidden. Currently it is 1.43 GB in size. Thanks a lot man, you steered me on the right direction.

Comment: No Problem :-) ,just bear in mind appdata stores all your application data e.g emails, program settings etc, so just make a backup, or copy what you need first before deleting. Deleting it wont hurt your pc as long as you create another user first, as its only the settings for each user, I wouldn't suggest deleting the folder directly, if you go to the profile manager like I suggested above & remove the profile this will delete it the proper way. If you go through it manually you can delete most things in there (Nothing Microsoft Related), just remember that this will reset any apps to default

Comment: Thanks, I would think that using the default tool in windows 7 should take care of this task in a safe way.